# OpenCV function HoughLines(), where should I consider the origin of the image?

Tags: c++, math, opencv, hough-transform

I would like to detect some lines via the standard Hough transform and filter the result according to a theta value so that the remaining lines would be the ones that have some specific orientation.

What I'm curious about is, in the function `HoughLines`, where is the origin that this function calculates each theta value from? For example, if I have an image of size width x height, what is the origin's coordinates? Is it (0,height) or (0,0)?

I assume it's somewhere between the 4 corners of the image but I'm not so sure. If anybody could clear this out, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The origin seen in this picture from opencv docs:

[image]

Is (0, heigh) in the image, the bottom left corner

Comment: I'm coding according to it and it seems working right. Thanks!

Comment: well **no**. the origin is always (0,0). in OpenCV images, that is the top left corner. "(0,heigh)" is the bottom left corner, and it has no special significance. see *other answer* for direct reference to **documentation**

Answer (score 2):

lines – Output vector of lines.
Each line is represented by a two-element vector *(rho, theta)*

- *rho* is the distance from the coordinate origin (0,0) **(top-left corner of the image)**.
- *theta* is the line rotation angle in radians ( 0 = {vertical line}, pi/2 = {horizontal line} ).

from https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a

Answer (score -1):

It's the top-left corner of the image.

Comment: Could you cite some sources as to where you found this?

Comment: this answer is a strict *subset* of previously given answers. it adds _nothing_.